# Flume agent is not transferring the data into source to target folder using file_roll

Tags: hadoop, flume

hi am using below conf file for agent.

when i run the agent i am not getting anything in sink folder. could anyone advice on this?

```
# Define a memory channel called ch1 on agent1
agent1.channels.ch1.type = memory

agent1.sources.spool.type = spooldir
agent1.sources.spool.channels = ch1
agent1.sources.spool.spoolDir = /logs/source
agent1.sources.spool.fileHeader = true

agent1.sinks.fr1.type = file_roll
agent1.sinks.fr1.channel = ch1
agent1.sinks.fr1.sink.directory = /logs/sink

agent1.channels = ch1
agent1.sources = spool
agent1.sinks = fr1
```

Comment: Do you have the write permission on /logs/sink?

Comment: Please, post flume log